# How to remove Scope and declaredType from json.I am using jackson parser

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

This is my output

```
{\"dealReleaseReference\":[{\"name\":\"DealReleaseReference\",\"declaredType\":\"java.lang.Object\",\"scope\":\"net.ddex.xml._2011.ern_main._33.ReleaseDeal\",\"value\":{\"name\":\"ReleaseReference\",\"declaredType\":\"java.lang.String\",\"scope\":\"net.ddex.xml._2011.ern_main._33.Release\",\"value\":\"Rs9973241\",\"nil\":false,\"globalScope\":false,\"typeSubstituted\":false},\"nil\":false,\"globalScope\":false,\"typeSubstituted\":true}],\"deal\":[{\"dealTerms\":{\"commercialModelType\":[{\"value\":\"PAY_AS_YOU_GO_MODEL\"}],\"usage\":[{\"useType\":[{\"value\":\"PERMANENT_DOWNLOAD\"},{\"value\":\"ON_DEMAND_STREAM\"}]}],\"territoryCode\":[\"Worldwide\"],\"priceInformation\":[{\"priceRangeType\":{\"value\":\"SINGLE3\",\"namespace\":\"PADPIDA2010051102D\"}}],\"validityPeriod\":[{\"startDate\":{\"value\":1435343400000}}]}},{\"dealTerms\":{\"commercialModelType\":[{\"value\":\"SUBSCRIPTION_MODEL\"}],\"usage\":[{\"useType\":[{\"value\":\"CONDITIONAL_DOWNLOAD\"},{\"value\":\"ON_DEMAND_STREAM\"}]}],\"territoryCode\":[\"Worldwide\"],\"priceInformation\":[{\"priceRangeType\":{\"value\":\"SINGLE3\",\"namespace\":\"PADPIDA2010051102D\"}}],\"validityPeriod\":[{\"startDate\":{\"value\":1435343400000}}]}},{\"dealTerms\":{\"commercialModelType\":[{\"value\":\"ADVERTISEMENT_SUPPORTED_MODEL\"}],\"usage\":[{\"useType\":[{\"value\":\"CONDITIONAL_DOWNLOAD\"},{\"value\":\"ON_DEMAND_STREAM\"}]}],\"territoryCode\":[\"Worldwide\"],\"priceInformation\":[{\"priceRangeType\":{\"value\":\"SINGLE3\",\"namespace\":\"PADPIDA2010051102D\"}}],\"validityPeriod\":[{\"startDate\":{\"value\":1435343400000}}]}}],\"effectiveDate\":1438108200000}
```

I want to remove Scope from json and declare type

This is my class

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2015.08.07 at 04:23:43 PM IST 
//


package net.ddex.xml._2011.ern_main._33;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


/**
 * A Composite containing details of one or more Deals pertaining to one
 *                 or more Releases.
 * 
 * <p>Java class for ReleaseDeal complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ReleaseDeal">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="DealReleaseReference" type="{http://ddex.net/xml/20110630/ddex}LocalReleaseAnchorReference" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *         &lt;element name="Deal" type="{http://ddex.net/xml/2011/ern-main/33}Deal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 *         &lt;element name="EffectiveDate" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="LanguageAndScriptCode" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ReleaseDeal", propOrder = {
    "dealReleaseReference",
    "deal",
    "effectiveDate"
})
public class ReleaseDeal  {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "DealReleaseReference", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected List<JAXBElement<Object>> dealReleaseReference;
    @XmlElement(name = "Deal", required = true)
    protected List<Deal> deal;
    @XmlElement(name = "EffectiveDate", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar effectiveDate;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "LanguageAndScriptCode")
    protected String languageAndScriptCode;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the dealReleaseReference property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the dealReleaseReference property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getDealReleaseReference().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Object }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<JAXBElement<Object>> getDealReleaseReference() {
        if (dealReleaseReference == null) {
            dealReleaseReference = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<Object>>();
        }
        return this.dealReleaseReference;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the deal property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the deal property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getDeal().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link Deal }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Deal> getDeal() {
        if (deal == null) {
            deal = new ArrayList<Deal>();
        }
        return this.deal;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the effectiveDate property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getEffectiveDate() {
        return effectiveDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the effectiveDate property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setEffectiveDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.effectiveDate = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the languageAndScriptCode property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getLanguageAndScriptCode() {
        return languageAndScriptCode;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the languageAndScriptCode property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setLanguageAndScriptCode(String value) {
        this.languageAndScriptCode = value;
    }

}
```

This is the step I am using to convert the class into json

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
                        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
                //      objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
                        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
                        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
                        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

                        String releaseDealSTring="";
                        try {
                            releaseDealSTring = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(releaseDeal);

                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                            System.out.print(e.getStackTrace());
                        }
```

Thanks for the help.It has been the case with Jackson.How to remove.I have tried gson but fail.Jackson parsing it properly but addind scope and declaretype to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the class `JAXBElement` has instance variables `declaredType` and `scope`. Annotating them to ignore the values will prevent them from getting serialized.

For example, with jackson use `@JsonIgnore` annotation (inside `JAXBElement` class):

```
@JsonIgnore
private String declaredType;
@JsonIgnore
private String scope;
```

Comment: I have shared ReleaseDeal class also and there is not declaredtype and scope in that class you can check it

Comment: @ManojSingh no, it's not in ReleaseDeal  class, it's in JAXBElement class.

Comment: Should I override JAXBElement class and override the 2 properties??

Comment: If you can't modify source, you can try setting them to null before serializing.